# Extracting Number From String SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a normal SQL statement:

```
SELECT VALUE_ID, UF_CRM_TASK FROM b_uts_tasks_task
```

Now this returns a a different field everytime but they take the form of the following:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:7:"CO_2012";} or a:1:{i:0;s:5:"CO_12";} or a:1:{i:0;s:7:"CO_2017";}
```

Basically they're different everytime.  What I need is to just get the number after the CO_ part.  I have tried TRIM but because everything changes in the leading and trailing section I don't think this would work.

I have looked on Stack Overflow for a while and cannot find it.  I know how to do it in PHP:

```
$data = $row['UF_CRM_TASK'];    
$companyID = substr($data, strpos($data, "CO_") + 1);
$newCompanyID = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $companyID);
```

But not SQL.  Thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is.

Comment: So you can't extract that number after CO_ in an SQL statement? Ignore the PHP part, as that gives me the answer after the sql statement.  I need it in the SQL statement.  Thought it would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

In MYSQL is a bit ugly:

```sql
/*SUBSTRING_INDEX BASED ON CO_ AND THE LAST " - in 2 SUBSTRINGS*/
SELECT `VALUE_ID`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`UF_CRM_TASK`, 'CO_', -1), '"', 1) AS `COMPANY_ID` FROM `b_uts_tasks_task`
```

In PHP you can just [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize):

```php
$data = unserialize($row['UF_CRM_TASK']);
$companyID = str_replace('CO_', '', $data[0]);
```

eg:

```php
$data = unserialize('a:1:{i:0;s:5:"CO_12";}');
echo str_replace('CO_', '', $data[0]);
//==> 12
```

Comment: The issue lies that I need it within the SQL statement so it'd be something like TRIM(UF_CRM_TASK, C0_.....) AS companyID so that I can use it in the WHERE clause.  I don't want it as PHP.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know what a PHP serialization is.

Comment: Solved it in MySQL :)

Comment: In a `WHERE` clause you can use regular expressions as well, though, this is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CharIndex and SubString (Microsoft SQL) or

This is the sample code I made for my Microsoft SQL server:

```
declare @companyIdString varchar(50) = 'a:1:{i:0;s:7:"CO_2012";}'

print 'Company ID in a string: ' + @companyIdString
print 'Find first position: ' + Cast(charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString) as varchar(2))
print 'Locate the second position (the last "): ' + Cast(charindex('"', @companyIdString, charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString)+4) as varchar(2))
print 'Extracted Company Id: ' + substring(@companyIdString,charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString)+4, charindex('"', @companyIdString, charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString)+4) - charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString) - 4)

select 
@companyIdString as CompanyIdString,
substring(@companyIdString,charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString)+4, charindex('"', @companyIdString, charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString)+4) - charindex('"CO_', @companyIdString) - 4) as CompanyId
```

I also made the same code on a mySQL server:

```
set @companyIdString := 'a:1:{i:0;s:7:"CO_2012";}';

select 
@companyIdString as CompanyIdString, 
substring_index(substring_index(substring_index(@companyIdString, '"', 2), '"', -1), '_', -1) as CompanyId
```

The substring_index starts by locating the second " (string is now a:1:{i:0;s:7:"CO_2012), then it searches backward with the -1 to locate the first " (string is now CO_2012). And then it searches backward for the underscore (string is now 2012).